# field has value confirmed but still get unwrap error?

Tags: swift2, option-type, unwrap, forced-unwrapping

This block of code fails when trying to set appURL, even though the if test succeeds and that the managed object contact has all fields set to non nil values and for certain contact.facebook has a value so I cant see why I am getting found nil while trying to unwrap?

```
func openFacebook() {

    if (contact.facebook) != nil && (contact.facebook) != "" {

        // build url to users facebook page
        let appURL = NSURL(string: String(format: "fb://profile=%@", contact.facebook!))!

        // build url to user page on facebook web site
        let webURL = NSURL(string: String(format: "http://www.facebook.com/%@", contact.facebook!))!

        openURL(appURL, webURL: webURL)
    }
}
```

Comment: what does contact.facebook returns ? you can safely unwrap the value using if let construct.

Comment: After so long trying to find the error it turns out it was because contact.facebook had a space in the literal value and it was NSURL throwing a wobbly!  Changing code to use regex now!

Comment: that's good if you found the problem.

Comment: Yep, was driving me mad...how do I close this question...do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to do it in a better way like :

```
func openFacebook() {

    if let contact = contact.facebook where contact != "" {

        // build url to users facebook page
        let appURL = NSURL(string: String(format: "fb://profile=%@", contact))!

        // build url to user page on facebook web site
        let webURL = NSURL(string: String(format: "http://www.facebook.com/%@", contact))!

        openURL(appURL, webURL: webURL)
    }
}
```

I think this will a better cleaner way to do `nil` checks and not force unwraping values later on.